# Ruby socket server and parsing input stream

Tags: ruby

I noob in Ruby and I have a problem.
I have input stream of plain text from syslog-ng. Text separated '\n' symbol. I want listen tcp port and parse input stream.

```
require 'socket

server = TCPServer.new 614
client = server.accept

loop do
  input += client.recv(1024)
  line = input.split(/\n/)
  while line.length > 1
    #here would be code for parsing
    puts line.delete_at(0)
  end
  input = line[0]
end
```

After start I get one string and nothing else. Why it can be? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing quotation in your require line.

I would highly recommend reading "Programming Ruby" https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby